# How to politely convey that you don't want to be tagged in irrelevant social media posts?

Tags: friends, social-media, boundaries

Some people have the habit of mass-tagging people on irrelevant posts. Mostly they don't have bad intentions but it's really noisy and I would like it stopped.

How to tell these people not to tag me without creating an argument? Even on sites like Facebook you can limit the tagging by making it permission based but you still get a notification every time asking for permission to approve or disapprove whether that tagged post would appear on your timeline.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Contact them privately to avoid any potential embarassment. Consider framing your request in the context of why you care about it: "Hey, my timeline is really noisy. Can you avoid tagging me on so many posts?" That will make it clear that you're primarily concerned about that sort of posts and not making any other rejection of them as a person.

Answer (score 7):

Social media tend to make it so easy to tag others by default. However, you can normally handle it by making it harder.

My approach here is to go through the Account settings and look for a way to manually review these tagging options (see [How to Control Unwanted Tagging of Facebook Photos](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/prevent-facebook-tagging/) for Facebook).

Also, you may consider:

- If this happens on pictures you feel embarrassed about, just make those private so your other friends cannot see them!
- If these people are always filling your main page with such posts, consider asking politely them not to do so. If they continue, just block them!

Answer (score 6):

People don't always know what settings they can use to prevent tagging, notifications and many other features of FaceBook.

Recently I tagged a [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) friend on 
 FaceBook in a photo I thought they might be interested in. The post didn't appear on their timeline, they had their settings set to approve tags.

The person inbox messaged me and asked to remove the tag. I stated it wasn't on his timeline so there was no worry. But, he said he didn't want to have to approve or not approve it. Now that may sound trivial, but I respected his notions about it.

Being on the receiving end of such, a polite private message is often a good way to resolve these types of FaceBook issues. Particularly if a person continually is tagging you when you don't want that.

Answer (score 2):

"Hey, I think you tagged me in your post by mistake?  I don't think it has anything to do with me.  Did you mean a different Ankit?"

You are clearly stating that this is irrelevant to you while allowing them the face-saving of pretending it was an innocent mistake.

If they insist they tagged you purposely--and will continue to do so--then I'd go with something along the lines of, "I have to watch my privacy settings and Facebook can be weird with tags.  If you don't mind, please don't tag me--I see your page all the time and I'll notice it."

Source--worked with my crazy sister-in-law.

Answer (score 1):

You are unlikely to change their behavior in any means. Some people behave that way years after reaching legal adulthood. You can write them hundred ways, they will forget when fully immersed in their tagging spree. Take it or leave it.

You can remove them from 'friends', if you can't cope with ignoring notifications. Otherwise, just ignore the notifications, and the problem is solved. Mass taggers are unlikely to notice that some of people they 'tagged' don't appear on tags.